# Excel links on rota

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to do a rota that is currently done on two spreadsheets. One shows the member of staff where they are working the other tells us that where they are working has cover by a member of staff. There are 14 places to work and 30 members of staff. Is it possible to get both Rota talking to each other so if a change occurs the place knows as well as the staff?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This site is not really for solving business issues for you. And this is not a script writing service. BUT...if you ***[edit]*** your question to be more specific about what you've tried with Excel, including formulas, and where you got stuck, it may be more "on topic", lessening the chances of being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Create multiple sheets and give them some reasonable names

[image]

Then you can refer to cells on different sheets using following notation:

```
'SheetName'!CellAddress
```

For example to pull value intp cell `A:1` on `Sheet1` from `B:3` on `Sheet2` you would type the following formulat into `A:1` on `Sheet1`:

```
='Sheet2'!B3
```

Note that you have to be aware of [circular references](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/circular-reference.html). One cell can point at another cell, but two cells cannot point at each other - this would create a circular reference. So in your case you can have multiple spreadsheets updated based on data from one, but not otherwise.

For more complex and flexible solutions look at [VBA scripts](http://excelvbatutor.com/vba_tutorial.html)

Comment: Would I be able to get sheet 2 to look down a column (date) for its name and correspond it to column 1 which will be staff name?

Comment: depends on how much effort you are willing to put into what you are doing.

Comment: I currently do the off duty every month for work and have to balance two different ones. One for staff and one for the location they are going to. If I do it once then this will help every month!!

Comment: as CharlieRB has already stated - this is not a script writing service. you can try to do it yourself and ask for help if you don't succeed, but you need to show that you tried